# Why is R adding an extra element to my vector?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have to create a for loop that takes vector z1, squares it, and then creates vector z2 with those vectors (yes I know there is a vectorization but this is a homework problem). I've got everything down except for SOME reason it adds on a trailing element to said vector.

```
z1 <- c(1, 8, 19, 17, 65, 103, 48, 17, 23, 34)

# Sort z1 in descending order
z1 <- sort(z1, decreasing = TRUE)

# Create empty vector z2
z2 <- c()

for (i in 1:10){
 z2[i] <- z1[i]*z1[i]
 z2 <- c(z2,z2[i])
}

print(z2)
```

Here's the vector it prints

```
[1] 10609  4225  2304  1156   529   361   289   289    64     1     1
```

If you notice it has 11 elements while my original z1 vector only has 10. Why?

Comment: Why not use `z1^2`?  But you need to drop the line: `z2 <- c(z2,z2[i])`  because when `z2[10]` arrives `z2` already fully assigned.

Comment: My expected output is

    [1] 10609  4225  2304  1156   529   361   289   289    64     1

Comment: Also @RichardScriven if I remove that line how am I supposed to construct the new vector that shows those values? I know the easy way is z1^2 but the question requires me to use a for loop.

Comment: You want something like `for (i in 1:10){ tmp <- z1[i]*z1[i]; z2 <- c(z2,tmp)}` so you have a 'holding cell' for your calcuation. Or even better just do `for (i in 1:10){ z2[i] <- z1[i]*z1[i]}`

Comment: In the last iteration you first assign the 10th value and then you append to it.

Comment: @thelatemail Oh jeeze. I am SO DUMB. As soon as you pointed it out I saw exactly what I was doing wrong. Thank you for the help. You'd think I'd be able to avoid these mistakes after a year of MATLAB but no. Haha.

Comment: I agree you should first understand vectorised operations like using z1^2 instead of what you are doing.

Comment: @latorrefabian unfortunately my professor disagrees. I know about vectorised operations from my work in MATLAB but this is how they want to teach it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First point: You can do this operation without a loop by using the vectorized `^` primitive function.

```
z1 ^ 2
# [1] 10609  4225  2304  1156   529   361   289   289    64     1
```

But here's what's happening in your code.  Basically you need to remove the line

```
z2 <- c(z2, z2[i])
```

because on the previous line you have already completed the assignment of the `z2` vector, leaving the final run with `c(z2[1:10], z2[10])`.  If you want to continue using a loop, just remove that line.

```
## note the difference in initializing z2
## memory allocation is more efficient than building in the loop
z2 <- vector(typeof(z1), length(z1))

for (i in seq_along(z2)) {
    z2[i] <- z1[i]*z1[i]
}
```

And then we have

```
z2
# [1] 10609  4225  2304  1156   529   361   289   289    64     1
```

Comment: notice that defining the length of z2 is not necessary, you can assign z2 <-c() and then z[3] <- 1 will just fill with na's the first and second position.

Comment: Not necessary, but more efficient to allocate the memory for the vector.